# when i click logout button, instead of redirecting me to the login page it just adds login.php to the already existing url

Tags: php, html

so... my logout page shows:

```
if(isset($_POST['logoutButton'])){
    $user = getUser();
    mysqli_query($dbConn, "DELETE FROM active_users WHERE User = '".(int) $user['ID']."'");
    echo"this worked";
    header("Location:index.php");
    exit();}
```

I have an active users DB to see if a user is logged in and when they click the logout button it is supposed to delete them from this database and send them back to the login page.
but when i click on the logout button from another page my localhost url shows:
"http://localhost/Schedules/Messaging.php/logout.php/".
My issue is that the webpage i was on when i clicked the logout button showed:
"http://localhost/Schedules/Messaging.php/".
why is it that when i click the logout button it doesn't redirect me, it just adds the "logout.php/" and does nothing.
 sometimes it even says it redirected too many times.

just deleted the ECHO portion of my code and still have the same result.
sometimes it shows this too...
This page isn’t working localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: remove the echo before the header. It won't work when there's output before.

Comment: and this `Messaging.php/logout.php/` looks like a problem in the logout-button, that we don't see.

Comment: *"My issue is that the webpage i was on when i clicked the logout button showed"* - Why does it do that?  That seems like the issue to focus on here.  If you've determined that the problem starts *before* the code you're showing us then what use is the code you're showing us?

Comment: Your problem is not on the logout page code, is on the href attribute of the link to the logout page. Maybe post it here so we can help.

Comment: i removed the ECHO but it is still not doing what it is supposed to do...

Comment: I have an active users DB that doesn't get deleted, it doesn't send me to index.php/ and it still says messaging.php/logout.php/

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff has said,

If you put echo or any kind of output before header, It will never redirect you to the URL. If you want to put "This worked...", you have to use JavaScript instead.